# Get line of PDF file after a specific line

Tags: java, string, file-io, pdfbox, text-processing

I use `Apache PDFBox` to parse text from pdf file. I tried to get a line after a specific line.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("my.pdf"));
if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = stripper.getText(document);
    System.out.println("Text from pdf:" + text);
} else{
    log.info("File is encrypted!");
}
document.close();
```

Sample:

> Sentence 1, nth line of file
>
> Needed line
>
> Sentence 3, n+2th line of file

I tried to get all the lines from file in an array, but it is unstable, because unable to filter to a specific text. It is problem also in second solution, that is why I am looking for a `PDFBox` based solution.
Solution 1:

```
String[] lines = myString.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Solution 2:

```
String neededline = (String) FileUtils.readLines(file).get("n+2th")
```

Comment: *"but it is unstable, because unable to filter to a specific text"* - can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Your solution 1 should work for basic formatted PDFs produced by an editor like Microsoft Word. It is in fact the same line separator used by PDFBox source code. I suspect there are many strange cases where PDFs have odd formatting that give you unstable results, but you can't control that unless you control the creation of the PDFs you need to text mine. Here's a tutorial that captures lines from a PDF, but it only works if you have a well formatted PDF. Moreover, you would simply call `lines.get(index)` to get the line number you need after working through this tutorial:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the [source code](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/8dd69d595104ab964b8e1eebf0b753b0e51814f4/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java#L115) for the `PDFTextStripper` class uses the exact same line ending as you, so your first attempt is as close to correct as possible using PDFBox.

You see, the `PDFTextStripper` [`getText`](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/8dd69d595104ab964b8e1eebf0b753b0e51814f4/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java#L193-L198) method calls the [`writeText`](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/8dd69d595104ab964b8e1eebf0b753b0e51814f4/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java#L222-L237) method which just writes to an output buffer line by line with the [`writeString`](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/8dd69d595104ab964b8e1eebf0b753b0e51814f4/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java#L737-L751) method in the exact same way as you have already tried. The result returned from this method is the buffer.toString().

Therefore, given a well formatted PDF, it would seem the question you are really asking is how to filter an array for specific text. Here are some ideas:

First, you captures lines in an array like you said.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class Main {

    static String[] lines;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("my2.pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = stripper.getText(document);
        lines = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Here's a method to get a complete String by any line number index, easy:

```
// returns a full String line by number n
static String getLine(int n) {
    return lines[n];
}
```

Here's a linear search method that finds a string match and returns the first line number where found.

```
// searches all lines for first line index containing `filter`
static int getLineNumberWithFilter(String filter) {
    int n = 0;
    for(String line : lines) {
        if(line.indexOf(filter) != -1) {
            return n;
        }
        n++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

With the above, it possible to get only the line number for your matched search:

```
System.out.println(getLine(8)); // line 8 for example
```

Or, the entire String line that contains your matched search:

```
System.out.println(lines[getLineNumberWithFilter("Cat dog mouse")]);
```

This all seems pretty straight forward and works only under the assumption that lines can be split into arrays by the line separator. If the solution is not as simple as the above ideas, I believe **the source of your problem may not be in your implementation with PDFBox but rather with the PDF source you are trying to text mine**.

Here's a link to a tutorial that also does what you are trying to do:

https://www.tutorialkart.com/pdfbox/extract-text-line-by-line-from-pdf/

Again, same approach...

Comment: Try also switching the sort option in the stripper.